# what is the most efficient way to write this sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ADUser parent table like this:

```
ADUser
------
Id => uniqueidentifier
FirstName => varchar(100)
LastName => varchar(100)
CreatedBy => uniqueidentifier
UpdatedBy => uniqueidentifier
```

And I have a [User] child table used to store an additional PersonalEmail user attribute like this:

```
User
-------
Id => uniqueidentifier
ADUserId => uniqueidentifier
PersonalEmail => varchar(100)
CreatedBy => uniqueidentifier
UpdatedBy => uniqueidentifier
```

I can write a query like this to get FirstName, LastName and PersonalEmail of all users:

```
SELECT 
    adu.FirstName, 
    adu.LastName,
    u.PersonalEmail
FROM 
    ADUser adu
JOIN 
    [User] u ON adu.Id = u.ADUserId
```

But let's say that I need to add the following columns to the result set to reflect `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` columns from the `[User]` table:

```
CreatedByName (user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName)
UpdatedByName (user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName)
```

What would be the most efficient way to update my query to resolve these additional columns?

Comment: you want to update before selecting? why don't you send values of `created by` at the time of `insertion` of user and same for `Update` when someone edits the details? :S

Comment: @ARr0w - I just want to figure out proper joins in this query so I can resolve the CreatedBy/UpdatedBy guids in the User table with the matching FirstName/LastName equivalents

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN back the User table with a different table alias

```
SELECT 
    adu.FirstName, 
    adu.LastName,
    u.PersonalEmail,
    CreatedByName  = c.FirstName  + ' ' + c.LastName,
    UpdateByName  = p.FirstName  + ' ' + p.LastName
FROM 
    ADUser adu
INNER JOIN 
    [User] u ON adu.Id = u.ADUserId
INNER JOIN
    [ADUser] c ON u.CreatedBy = c.Id
INNER JOIN
    [ADUser] p ON u.UpdatedBy = p.Id
```

Comment: but FirstName and Last Name belong to the ADUser table not to the User table